# Windows.Device.Usb not for Mobile Devices, What Is?

Tags: android, windows, uwp, windows-10, usb

I am researching a new project. As a preface, I am totally new to Windows 10 development, I'm coming from Android and iOS. It is a Windows 10 application that manages the transfer of large amounts of database data to mobile devices. I know that the interface mechanism is via USB but I am having a tough time with determining what API to use. I explored the Windows.Device.Usb road and had luck detecting the devices but have come to find out that this API is meant to handle 'miscellaneous' devices using winusb.sys drivers.

So my main question is, what (if any) API is to be used for communicating and managing mobile devices?

Any info given helps me in my research so Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what I understand, you seems like to access mobile device folders. In UWP app, you can use the [KnownFolders.RemovableDevices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_RemovableDevices) to get the removable devices folder. See the topic [Access the SD card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/access-the-sd-card) to get the details.

Comment: Great. Thanks for this suggestion. It completes another piece of the puzzle.